# makefiles and linking a library in a different folder

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I've search around a bit on StackOverflow and tried a few suggestions but as of yet nothing has solved the problem.

I'm making a makefile for a school project and as part of my project I'm generating a static library and linking against it. The compiler throws an error when it gets to a header include in the static library. The code for that is just `#include "StringUtil.h"`

So in the makefile I have these relevant parts of code

```
LINKFLAGS=-Llib/ -lHTMLtools

bin : lib $(BIN_FILE)
lib : $(LIB_OBJ_FILES)
    ar r lib/libHTMLtools.a $(LIB_OBJ_FILES)

$(BIN_FILE) : $(OBJ_FILES) #This is only obj/crawler.o for now
    g++ -o bin/crawler obj/crawler.o
obj/crawler.o : src/crawler.cpp inc/crawler.h
    g++ -c -static $(LINKFLAGS) -o obj/crawler.o -I inc src/crawler.cpp
```

so whenever I run the `make bin` command it generates `lib.libHTMLtools.a` as expected but when it gets to the
`g++ -c -static $(LINKFLAGS) -o obj/crawler.o -I inc src/crawler.cpp`
 line it returns this error.

```
src/crawler.cpp:2:24: fatal error: StringUtil.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Where is your StringUtil.h file is located? If it's not in the "inc" directory, it will not find it

Comment: It is part of the library I built. but I could always reference it from utils/inc/StringUtil.h if I can't find another way to do it before this is due

Comment: @bob when you say it's part of the library you built do you mean the header files get copied over to a specific output directory when the static library gets built? Can you also add what the directory structure looks like for the source and binary output?

Comment: no :/ I don't think they get copied over... should they? I just imagined that the .h files were bundled in the .a file...

Comment: @bob no, that's not how it works. Take a look at crazy's answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, library files are not enough. They are not used when compiling source code, but only when linking. To compile source file, you need to include headers. But the compiler need to know where to find it. Try adding `-I utils/inc` to your last line like this

```
g++ -c -static $(LINKFLAGS) -o obj/crawler.o -I inc -I utils/inc src/crawler.cpp
```

Comment: Then... oh... Yep, that worked! Thanks! Why then AREN'T the .h files referencable from the library? That would make life a lot easier wouldn't it?

Comment: C and C++ are made that way. They fix it in Java and C# ( among others ). It's the legacy we need to live with ;-)